# mcrypt installed and enabled but magento checkout throwing undefined function mcrypt_module_open()

Tags: php, magento, mcrypt

I have a Magento 1.9 site installed and all necessary php extensions. The site works, but when I get to checkout/onepage I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /path/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63
```

I understand this typically means that mcrypt is not installed, but looking at the contents of phpinfo(); reveal that it is installed and enabled

[portion of phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWam3.png)

I am running on php 5.3.29 using apache on a mac. I used homebrew to install php53 and php53-mcrypt. I am curious to know why the mcrypt_module_open() function cannot be found if I have mcrypt enabled.

Comment: open up php.ini and allow the php_mycrypt.dll extension by removing the ;(semicolon).

;extension=php_mcrypt.dll to extension=php_mcrypt.dll

Comment: Thank you for the comment. .dll filetypes are extensions for windows. I'm running on a mac and have it linked to the specific location of mcrypt and it's showing as enabled when I run phpinfo();